# Angular ui-router loading view twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I'm using angular ui-router in my angular application. For the routing part I've written

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider

    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
           controller : function($scope,$state){
            $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
              console.log("home content loaded",$state.current);
            })
          }
    })

    // nested list with custom controller
    .state('home.list', {
        url: '/list',
        template: 'I am using a list.'
    })

    // nested list with just some random string data
    .state('home.paragraph', {
        url: '/paragraph',
        template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
    }) 

});
```

In partial-home.html I've wriiten:-

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
  <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>

  <a ui-sref=".list" class="btn btn-primary">List</a>
  <a ui-sref=".paragraph" class="btn btn-danger">Paragraph</a>

</div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

Now when I'm executing this app in browser, if I open the the route

```
/home
```

The browser console is showing "home content loaded" once, and then if I click on the list link, the addressbar changes to

```
/home/list
```

And then also the console is shown once.

But if I refresh the browser tab at that time (when the route is home/list), the console is shown twice. Please help me why this thing happening.

Answer (score 2):

These are nested views. The reason why there are two messages in your console after reload is:
When you start at /home, the home state is loaded. When you go to /home/list over there, only home.list need to be loaded since the home state is already loaded. When you reload there are two states that need to be loaded: home and home.list.

Edit: i dont have enough reputation so i cant comment. i guess that you use ui-view inside home template which causes child and parent to share the same scope. u are listening to both child's and parent's scope for the event. so it is natural to be called twice

Comment: As list is child of home, then it'll obviously load the view for home first and then the view for list. But here the view for home is being loaded twice. I have not added any console on list viewContentLoaded. Another thing is, when I'm in /home and clicking on the list link, then also the same thing should happen. But in that case, it's only showing one console.

Answer (score 1):

because home.list is a child state of home and when you reload page for home.list
it first initializes view of home controller than view of list controller so $viewContentLoaded is called twice

i guess that you use ui-view inside home template which causes child and parent to share the same scope. u are listening to both child's and parent's scope for the event. so it is natural to be called twice

Comment: As list is child of home, then it'll obviously load the view for home first and then the view for list. But here the view for home is being loaded twice. I have not added any console on list viewContentLoaded. Another thing is, when I'm in /home and clicking on the list link, then also the same thing should happen. But in that case, it's only showing one console.

Comment: i guess that you use ui-view inside home template which causes child and parent to share the same scope. u are listening to both child's and parent's scope for the event. so it is natural to be called twice

Comment: I've defined a controller for list also, so that it does not get the same scope. Still same thing is happening.

Comment: scope is not inherited between controllers it is inherited between views. if child view is inside parent view they get the same scope

Comment: Then same thing should happen when I'm in home state and I click on the list link to go to the home.list state.

Comment: no it shouldnt because home view is already loaded (you already got event for home view). when you go to home.list from home it just loads child view so $viewContentLoaded is called once

Comment: Any idea how I can fix it, actually I'm loading some data using $http when the view is loaded, thus those data are loading twice. I can add an extra variable when the data is being loaded, thus the http is not called twice, any other better option?

Comment: you shouldnt load data on $viewContentLoaded. you better use resolve or load data on controller load. why do you wait for view to load data anyways? go with resolve or load data inside controller

Comment: The controller will be loaded with the app, but I want to load the data when the view is shown, may be user does not open the view, then why I'll load the data?

Comment: you have something wrong with your logic. if user wont open the page, controller shouldn't be initialized too