# $stateProvider loading a state twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My state configuration goes something like this:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {

  $authProvider.facebook({
    clientId: '16250xxxxxx',
    scope: 'user_friends'
  });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  $stateProvider
    .state('core', {
      abstract: true,
      template: '<ui-view>',
      resolve: {

        'authStatus' : function($auth, $q, User) {
          var defer = $q.defer();

          $auth.authenticate('facebook').then(function(result) {
            User.update(result.data.user);
            defer.resolve();
          });

          return defer.promise;

        }

      }
    })
    .state('home', {
      parent: 'core',
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html'
    })
    .... 
    .... other states
```

When my application loads, it enters the resolve block of 'core' state twice.

This causes the facebook authentication window to open twice..

Any clue why it would execute the core state twice ?

Comment: i think this is because the home state is a child of the core state so it loads the core and then core + home here some one had a similar problem i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621736/angular-ui-router-loading-view-twice

Comment: should resolve in order, create demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason for this occurence.

The satellizer $auth service would redirect to a default url upon resolving the authentication.

I simply had to reset that to '/home' in the config section of angular app

```
$authProvider.loginRedirect = '/home';
```